# Convert ESRI Shapefile to (lat, long) points for each region

Tags: gis, latitude-longitude, shapefile, esri, anylogic

I have an ESRI Shapefile with multiple subregions. I need the lat/long points that make up those regions and their unique identifier so I can convert them into a custom format for use in AnyLogic. (AnyLogic can read Shapefiles using OpenMap, but I cannot access the lat/long points using the API.) How would I get them? Is there a command line tool to do this? How would I do it myself, if need be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you can use [OGR2OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to do something with your shapes. 
May be you could find [this](http://levien.zonnetjes.net/?q=shapefiles) helpful.

Comment: Great -- while I can't investigate it now, that looks like it will do what I need! Thanks!